# Fonts and Lines on Retina display

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, retina-display

i have finished my app in a @1x version and have created a lot of the interface with code, meaning:

- UILabels
- UIViews

and all looks great. if i now use the app on a retina display obviously everything scales up to @2x. I have some graphics that i designed with fireworks/photoshop and of course have made @2x versions of them that work just fine. My problem are the standard interface elements as noted above.

Question: How would i go about

- Having a font in a UILabel that has a 1px stroke on both resolutions, but double the hight and width on @2x ?
- Having a UIView with height 1px (as separator of the screen) on both resolutions? 2px lines on @2x are ok, but id really rather have them 1px of hight - looks just more elegant.

for creating a separator view i currently use:

```
UIView *separatorLine = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,320,1)];
[self.view addSubview:seperatorLine];
```

which works fine on @1x resolution but gets blown up to 2px height in @2x, instead of showing in the @2x as:

```
seperatorLine.frame == (0,400,640,1)
```

how would i need to change such a code to work on both resolutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for the screen scale by

```
CGFloat scale = ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] ? [UIScreen mainScreen].scale : 1.0);
```

If the scale equals 2.0 you are on a retina display and can change the frame of the separator, for example, to `CGRectMake(0.0, 200.0, 320.0, 0.5)`.

Comment: so basically :

if(2.0){seperator.frame = highres}
else {seperator.frame = lores}

addSubview:seperator?

Comment: and interesting: why do you use .5 as height, but still scale up the position?

Comment: Sorry, thought `seperatorLine.frame == (0,400,640,1)` was your default frame. Edited. And yes, you could do it like in your first comment, but the `if` should be `if (scale == 2.0)`.

Comment: okay - now its clear how to proceed for separators and such - do you have a suggestion about fonts as well? thats the only thing missing for an accept now :P the upvote is earned, thanks a lot so far!

Comment: You can't, and shouldn't, get a font with 1px strokes. The same font on retina and non-retina will be fine, it will just look better in retina. If you did do as you are asking the font would just look really spindly and thin. Same for the graphics, really - draw it all in points, not fonts, a 1px line on a retina display will be so thin it will look more like a fault on the screen.

Comment: allright =)
tried some stuff out and you are probably right! the lines look unbelievable sexy if they are just 1px in height on retina. fonts get rendered pretty well - so this answer fits my needs, thanks for the effort Jenox & commenters.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to worry about any of that when using Apple's Cocoa elements, that's the best part about retina display for us developers!

You need to @2x your graphics like you said you have done, but the device will automatically scale the Cocoa display elements as needed. Apple has made a clear distinction between "pixels" and "points" and frames are set using points. A point is 1px on a legacy display and 2px on a retina display. This means that in fact if you were to set your frame to `CGRectMake(0,400,640,1)` as you mentioned would put the line at the bottom of the screen and be twice the width of the screen (clipped by the bounds of the screen of course). If you really want that line to be 1px high on a retina display, make it an image. The standard image can be 320x1 and the @2x can be 640x1.

If you want to see what I mean but don't have a retina display device you can run in simulator and select from the menu Hardware > Device > iPhone (Retina)

Good luck.